# Possible to determine the location using 2 points and a location that has just angle differences of these 2 points?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a camera where I may view the offset in degrees for elevation and azimuth changes. I have it pointing to known locations and I have measured the angle difference for each.

I am trying to successfully calculate the camera's location based on those 2 points. If I need another point that is not a problem.

Using the formula #2 https://everything2.com/title/Triangulate I can calculate the Cross location, however, I need to be able to determine the heading for finer adjustment as I cannot guarantee I am not true north.

Comment: If you only know the angle x you could be anywhere on the arc of a circle https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/image-files/angles-in-circle.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually divide the problem into the planimetric solution (X and Y coordinates) on the one hand, and the altimetric solution (Z coordinate) on the other.

To determine the planimetric position we bisect 3 points with known coordinates. We use only their planimetric coordinates in the calculations and solve those of the station with the method known as the [Snellius–Pothenot problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snellius%E2%80%93Pothenot_problem).

Knowing the planimetric location of the station, the planimetric (horizontal) distance to any of the points can be obtained, and measuring the elevation angle to only one of them is enough to calculate the altimetric coordinate of the station. In practice, we take advantage of the bisection at the three points and calculate the altitude of the instrument as the arithmetic mean of the results obtained with each bisection independently.

This is valid since the main axis of the measuring instrument is oriented in the direction of the Z axis of the coordinate system of all points.

If your instrument is not verticalized, I suppose that the problem still has a solution (although I do not know the method to find it).